# Need java Regex to remove/replace the XML elements from specific string

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem in getting the correct Regular expression.I have below xml as string

```xml
    <user_input>
    <UserInput Question="test Q?" Answer=<value>0</value><sam@testmail.com>"
    </user_input>
```

Now I need to remove the xml character from Answer attribute only.
So I need the below:-

```xml
    <user_input>
    <UserInput Question="test Q?" Answer=value0value sam@testmail.com"
    </user_input>
```

I have tried the below regex but did not worked out:-

```
str1.replaceAll("Answer=.*?<([^<]*)>", "$1");
```

it's removing all the text before..

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*did not worked out*"?

Comment: So, you also want to insert a space right where `><` are? Can we replace all `><` with a space in arbitrary places? You cannot remove and insert at the same time, you'll need 2 regexes, or 1 regex and a simple replace.

Comment: Please do not use regex to modify XML - HTH ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `?` within the first group to make it none greedy, also you dont need `Answer=.*?`:

```
str1.replaceAll("<([^<]*?)>", "$1")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tW6zC3/1)

Comment: I have to remove this inside Answer Attribute only.if my string contains some other valid xml like <userinput> it should not touch that..overall outside of Answer="", it should not do anything

Comment: @samash So using regex is not a good choice for parsing `(X)Html` at all you may consider a proper parser!

Comment: I tested the above it did not worked fully.it replaced the tag of userinput also.

Comment: the problem is we don't have to parse the XML as we are middleware and the xml snippet inside answer attribute is creating problem for end system.so is there any regex which can solve my problem?

Comment: No we don't have the option to parse the xml.. but i am pretty sure by regex it can be done

Comment: @samash It could be very complicated and also its not an efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

`httpRequest.send("msg="+data+"&TC="+TC);` try like this

Answer (score 0):

Although variable width look-behinds are not supported in Java, you can work around it with `.{0,1000}` that should suffice.

Please check out this approach using 2 regexes, or 1 regex and 1 `replace`. Choose the one that suits best (I removed the `\n` line break from the first input string to show the flaw with using simple `replace`):

```
String input = "<user_input><UserInput Question=\"test Q?\" Answer=<value>0</value><sam@testmail.com>\"\n</user_input>";
String st = input.replace("><", " ").replaceAll("(?<=Answer=.{0,1000})[<>/]+(?=[^\"]*\")", "");
String st1 = input.replaceAll("(?<=Answer=.{0,1000})><(?=[^\"]*\")", " ").replaceAll("(?<=Answer=.{0,1000})[<>/]+(?=[^\"]*\")", "");
System.out.println(st + "\n" + st1);
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMEtfcjdiRjFIYjA):

```
<user_input UserInput Question="test Q?" Answer=value0value sam@testmail.com"                                                                                                                                                                          
</user_input>  

<user_input><UserInput Question="test Q?" Answer=value0value sam@testmail.com"                                                                                                                                                                         
</user_input>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your sample above, there is a trailing `"` after the email and `>` which I do not know if it was placed by error.

However, I will keep it there as according to your expected result, you need it to still be present.

This is my hack.

`(Answer=)(<)(value)(>)(.+?([^<]*))(</)(value)(><)(.+?([^>]*))(>)` to replace it with

```
$1$3$5$8 $10
```

**The explanation...**

`(Answer=)(<)(value)(>)` matches from Answer to the start of the value 0

`(.+?([^<]*)` matches the result from 0 or more right to the beginning `<` which starts the closing value tag

`(</)` here, I still select this since it was dropped in the previous expression

`(><)` I will later replace this with a space

`(.+?([^>]*)` This matches from the start of the email and excludes the `>` after the .com

`(>)` this one selects the last `>` which I will later drop when replacing.

The trailing `"` is not selected as I will rather not touch it as requested.